# can a basis for the tangent space of a manifold be found without any use of charts?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Every mention of a basis for the  tangent space of a manifold at a point I've encountered first chooses a chart near the point and defines the basis in terms of the chart. Is there a basis defined without any mention of charts?

Comment: Use derivations as the definition of tangent vectors, for example.

Comment: Once you've proved that it is a vector space, you can apply the theorem that every vector space has a basis.